# Convert uppercase string to lowercase using charAt

Tags: java, string

I was wondering what is exactly wrong with the following code. I'm getting error on the line after the if statement. This code takes a string with both uppercase and lowercase letters but returns the string after converting the uppercase letters to lowercase.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        toLowerCase("HeLloWoRlD!");
    }

    private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                str.charAt(i) = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.charAt(i)` cannot be the left hand side of an assignment operator. It's a value returned by a method call, you can't assign to it.

Besides, `String`s are immutable. You cannot modify the characters of `str`.
You'll have to create a new `String` for your method to return.

For example:

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append (Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            sb.append (str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to the following :

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
    StringBuffer lower = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            lower.append(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            lower.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return lower.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(toLowerCase("HeLloWoRlD!"));
}
```

A string is immutable so you can't change the existing one on the fly. Instead you can create a StringBuffer and append the values accordingly as you iterate over the original `str`.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable so you cannot change (reassign) the characters inside the string.
Here is the simplest solution, just using the built in method in String class:

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
    return str == null ? null : str.toLowerCase(); //consider str.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) if you are using non english language with special characters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of the String.charAt(i) which returns character Value at that position. It is not the reference location that you can assign a value to.

Please check the below documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-

You need to convert to a character Array the string if you want to modify it using the charAt feature

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
        char[] newStr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                newStr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return new String(newStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `charAt(i)` is used for getting character by index(position) in the string. However, You used it for setting, what is not right.

So, in your case, method  `toLowerCase()` should return new String object, for example.

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
  String returning_Str = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char test_char = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(test_char)) {
          test_char = Character.toLowerCase(test_char);
        }
        returning_Str += test_char;
    }
    return returning_Str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the content of a String. You have to create a new object instead:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        toLowerCase("HeLloWoRlD!");
    }

    private static String toLowerCase(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                str = new String(str.replace(str.charAt(i),Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i))));
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a variable the assign value on it.
This code will work as expected

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toLowerCase("HeLloWoRlD!"));
    }

    private static StringBuffer toLowerCase(String str) {
        StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c=str.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                c = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
                buf.append(c);
            }else{
                buf.append(c);
            }
        }
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str){

    return str.chars().map(Character::toLowerCase).collect(StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

}
```

or

```
private static String toLowerCase(String str){

    return str.toLowerCase();

}
```